# Java: Is there a way to create a pdf file in eclipse using just apache poi

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi

All of the methods that i've searched for seem to use itext libraries, but is there a way to just use apache poi libraries ?

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/.

Comment: Which file format(s)? You can, for example, use Apache POI to go from Word `.doc` to FO, then onwards from that to PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so.  POI is strictly for Microsoft documents and PDF was created by Adobe.  So the short and quick answer is no.

If you read the docs for Apache's POI project you'll read in the title "Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents".

[Apache POI Project](https://poi.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

POI is explicitly made for Microsoft Documents. Using itext is the easiest way to generate or create a PDF file within Java.